# Count Date Range for all rows in SQL DB

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to count how many days a user has clocked in within a certain date period, as the user can be clocked in for several days at a time i need to find the difference between the two dates and then count the total days for each column within the date period and only where the accountid matches.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where i am going wrong.

---

Database Table

```
id, datein, dateout, accountid
1, 2022-08-01, 2022-08-03, 1
2, 2022-08-04, 2022-08-05, 2
3, 2022-08-05, 2022-08-05, 1
4, 2022-08-05, 2022-08-08, 1
5, 2022-08-06, 2022-08-07, 2
6, 2022-08-06, 2022-08-08, 3
7, 2022-08-07, 2022-08-10, 1
8, 2022-08-08, 2022-08-08, 2
```

---

Code

```
<?php
$accountid =$user->data()->id;
$monthdate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 month")); 
$crrntdte=date("Y-m-d");
$query3=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DATEDIFF('datein', 'dateout') as monthlysessions from addsession where ((datein) between '$monthdate' and '$crrntdte') && (accountid='$accountid');");
$result3=mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
$sum_monthly_sessions=$result3['monthlysessions'];
?>

<?php echo $sum_monthly_sessions;?>
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATEDIFF is a product specific function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get sum of previous 30 days you can just add `SUM` before `DATEDIFF` and if you want to make it consecutive

```
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(dateout, datein) = 0, DATEDIFF(dateout, datein) +1, DATEDIFF(dateout, datein)))
```

you can use this, this kind of selection can be made better, but it's simplest.  But if you want to make it like past month e.g. it's August, so from 2022-08-01 to 2022-08-31, use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(dateout, datein) = 0, DATEDIFF(dateout, datein) + 1, DATEDIFF(dateout, datein))) 
FROM 
    addsession
WHERE 
    accountid = 1 
    AND MONTH(datein) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE());
```